# Error Code 0x84BB0001 when installing SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

OS: Windows Server 2012 R2

When attempting to install SQL Server 2016 on a Server that is already running SQL 2012 I receive 0x84BB0001. This stops my Database Engine Service from installing correctly.

There is no antivirus running.
Ive deleted the contents of C:/Users/[UserName]/AppData/Local/Microsoft_Corporatio 
Ive given admin rights to the following:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130

Really at a loss for what to do here?

```html
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
  Start time:                    2016-10-31 15:39:25
  End time:                      2016-10-31 15:53:10
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  FUALSNA_SQL
  Machine processor count:       1
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard (6.3.9600)
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2012      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 11.0.2100.60    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          SSMS                                     1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 11.0.2100.60    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2012                                                          Adv_SSMS                                 1033                 Enterprise Evaluation Edition 11.0.2100.60    No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         D:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

Product Update Status:
  User selected not to include product updates.

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLAgent$SQL
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Automatic
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161031_153925\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  EXTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  EXTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    SQL2016
  INSTANCENAME:                  SQL
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ISTELSVCACCT:                  <empty>
  ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBENGSVCACCOUNT:               <empty>
  PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              <empty>
  PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0
  PBPORTRANGE:                   <empty>
  PBSCALEOUT:                    false
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQL$SQL
  SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           FUALSNA\administrator
  SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT Service\SQLTELEMETRY$SQL
  SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:             <empty>
  SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1
  SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:           64
  SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64
  SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:          8
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  TCPENABLED:                    1
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 false
  UpdateSource:                  MU
  USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:            false
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161031_153925\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             The specified driver is invalid.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.1601.5&EvtType=0x476BF04A%400xDC80C325&EvtType=0x476BF04A%400xDC80C325

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Client Connectivity SDK
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Setup Support Files
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161031_153925\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

```html
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp: The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp: Inner exceptions are being indented
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp: 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp: Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.ScoException
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:     Message: 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         The specified driver is invalid.
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:     HResult : 0x84bb0001
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         FacilityCode : 1211 (4bb)
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:     Data: 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:       WatsonData = perf-MSSQL$SQL-sqlctr13.0.1601.5.dll@OpenSQLPerformanceData@CollectSQLPerformanceData@CloseSQLPerformanceData
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:       DisableRetry = true
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:     Inner exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         Message: 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:                 The specified driver is invalid.
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:                 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         HResult : 0x80004005
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         Error : 2001
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:         Stack: 
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.LoadPerformanceCounter(String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounterCore(String libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction, String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
(01) 2016-10-31 15:52:47 Slp:                 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.PerformanceCounter.RegisterPerformanceCounter(String libraryFileName, String openFunction, String collectionFunction, String closeFunction, String symbolInstallPath, String counterPrefixServiceName)
```

Comment: Questions about installations don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this particular issue, my solution was to download a new ISO from Microsoft. Appears that at some point my ISO was corrupted. New ISO worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I would repeatedly get this error when attempting to install MSSQL 2016 SP1 or SP2 on Windows Server 2012 R2 With latest updates as of OCT 2018.

> 0x84BB0001 A connection was successfully established with the server,
>   but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

**Solution:**

Re-enable TLS1.0 and attempt to install again. 
(We recently disabled TLS 1.0 on our Windows Server 2012R2 template.)
- You can check if TLS1.0 is disabled and enable it using IISCrypto Tool.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old post, but I recently struck this issue as I needed to install 2016 for vendor compatibility.

In my case the issue was the service accounts being used.

Solution was to install using the default NT Service virtual accounts then change to domain accounts post install (we were actually using group managed service accounts)